# Java schedulars

Tags: java, timer

What is the best way to implement a cron like scheduler in jsp & servelet based web application ?
Came across one option using the "Timer Service". Any other alternatives or any comments on timer services ?

Thanks in advance

Shamika

Answer (score 1):

Quartz- I've used it and it works really well.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/